# How to add the values of input box using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular5, angular7

[image]

I want to add the values of apple,orange and mango , then want to get the value in total. 
below is the code which I tried.

```
  <div class="row col-12 " ngModelGroup="cntMap">
    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label for="total">Total</label>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <input type="text" value="{{totalCount}}" class="form-control"
             name="totalCnt" [maxlength]="30" placeholder="Total" #totalCnt="ngModel" ngModel 
             [(ngModel)]="form.totalCnt">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-6 ml-auto">
      <label for="APPLE">Apple</label>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="APPLE" [maxlength]="30" placeholder="Enter" 
          #APPLE="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="form.APPLE" (change)="getCount($event)">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-6 ml-auto">
      <label for="ORANGE">Orange</label>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ORANGE" [maxlength]="30" placeholder="Enter" 
          #ORANGE="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="form.ORANGE" (change)="getCount($event)">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-6 ml-auto">
      <label for="MANGO">Mango</label>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MANGO" [maxlength]="30" placeholder="Enter" 
          #MANGO="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="form.MANGO" (change)="getCount($event)">
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

In component.ts file

```
  getCount(event: any) {
    var c = event.target.value;
    this.totalCount += parseInt(c);
    console.log("totalCount ", this.totalCount );
  }
```

**Problem:**

When I add the value in the input , its adding the count like:
10+10+10=30

After that when I change the Apple value fron 10 to 8, the total value is like:
10+10+10+8=38
Which means without clearing the data from input box, it is adding the value 8.

Can anybody help me to clear this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The flow which is happening currently is correct as the `getCount()` is adding the new value to existing total count.

What you should do instead is on every change event, re-add the values from all three input fields.

```
getCount(event: any) {
  this.totalCount = parseInt(this.form.APPLE) + parseInt(this.form.ORANGE) + parseInt(this.form.MANGO);
  console.log("totalCount ", this.totalCount );
}
```